# Excel 2010 as a client to SSAS 2008R2 doesn't show all members in named set

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

There is a feature to create custom mdx set in Excel 2010. I've created one - it combines members from different dimensions and works just fine in SSMS but in Excel I can see only half members of set.
Here is MDX query catched from Excel:

```
WITH
SET [13,14,Trash, MarkDown] as {
([Product].[Category].&[13], [Discounting].[Liquidity].[All discs])
,([Product].[Category].&[14], [Discounting].[Liquidity].[All discs])
,([Product].[Category].[All products], [Discounting].[Liquidity].[Liq group].&[1])
,([Product].[Category].[All products], [Discounting].[Liquidity].[Liq group].&[0])
}
SELECT NON EMPTY {[13,14,Trash, MarkDown]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS
  FROM [CubeName] 
WHERE ([Measures].[On hand qty]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

Excel shows values only for Category13 and Category14.
SSMS does more - it shows all values.

In Excel it looks like this:

```
             | category  13  |  category   14
on hand qty  |    150        |     200
```

In SSMS:

```
             | category  13  |  category   14  |  All products  | All products
             | All discs     |  All discs      |  Liq group 1   | Liq group 0
on hand qty  |    150        |     200         |      35        |      85
```

I've tried to make this set on the server side, but it't no use - result in excel is the same. Is it possible to have all set values in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

i've created two hidden members

```
  MEMBER [Product].[Category].[All Liq 1] as ([Product].[Category].[All], [Discounting].[Liquidity].[Liq group].&[1])
  MEMBER [Product].[Category].[All Liq 0] as ([Product].[Category].[All], [Discounting].[Liquidity].[Liq group].&[0])
```

then created set

```
{[Product].[Category].&[13], [Product].[Category].&[14], [Product].[Category].[All Liq 1], [Product].[Category].[All Liq 0]}
```

and it did exacly what was needed in excel.